# Should we have a tag for dice-related challenges?

Tags: discussion, tags

[A comment in the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges#comment51747_14298) prompted me to start this discussion - should we create [dice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice) and tag dice-related questions?

### Information

- From a [simple search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=dice+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano), I see 43 challenges related to dice (plus at least 2 challenges active in the Sandbox) right now
- There would be some overlap between [dice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice) and [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) - [dice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice) would likely end up being a more specific version of [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)

Comment: I'd like to distinguish challenges about the arrangement of numbers on a die from ones about generating random numbers from 1 to 6.

Comment: Alternatively, generalise the tag to [tag:polyhedra].

Comment: I don't think that polyhedra is a good generalization, as polyhedra is more about the shape, where dice cover lots of other things (such as the arrangement of the numbers, or the randomness involved)

Comment: @NathanMerrill I was thinking that polyhedra would actually emphasise the topology part, whereas dice could have too much emphasis on the randomness, as xnor says. Regardless of what tag we use, I feel like you should use [tag:random] in addition anyway. I can totally come up with non-random [tag:dice] challenges, where only the topology is important.

Comment: I'd agree with @MartinEnder here, I don't think there's any need to be so specific with tags. Also, not every dice-related challenge is related to randomness, see [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/149890/41024) for an example. Also, we already have a [tag:topology] tag.

Answer (score 9):

### No

1) There's no need to get this specific in our tagging, and
2) As pointed out in the comments, there's a lot of overlap with either [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) or [topology](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology), and
3) It doesn't necessarily have a useful quality that people would want to seek out (or avoid)

In addition, if we're looking strictly at numbers, there are [almost 100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=cards+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano) "cards" questions, of which 59 [aren't tagged](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=cards+-%5Bcard-games%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano) with [card-games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games) -- but I don't think we need a [card](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card) tag for the same reason we don't need a [dice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice) tag.

Answer (score 3):

As the person who suggested it, I'd like to defend the value of the tag. I don't think many people would want to follow it, although some people might want to hide it; but its real value would be in searching for duplicates. Being able to search for e.g. `[dice] visible is:q` would be much more efficient than searching for `dice visible is:q` and `die visible is:q` (particularly because the word *die* has non-dice-related meanings).

I agree that there would be overlap with [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random), but I don't see that this is a problem. Neither would be a subset of the other, and very few questions (5%) on this site are at the five-tag limit.

The tag system is meant to help the community, and I think that this tag would particularly help sandbox reviewers with dupe finding.